# EPPlus removing data validation

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

When i open an existing sheet that has data validation on some cells i want to remove the data validation, but the collection of data validations on the sheet and on the cells at run time shows there is no data validation on the cells

This came about because i delete a bunch of rows that have data validation on them, so the rows below shift up and then take on that data validation formula, in this case a list

i am developing in c# with Ep Plus

i basically need to know how to remove an existing data validation or stop the validation data being copied to the rows after rows are deleted

As part of my workflow i add data validation lists via c# code to a number of other cells. These show in the datavalidation property of the sheet but the validations that were already in place on the sheet do not show and i cant understand why

Comment: I know you can null a formula (`worksheet.Cells[3, 3].Formula = null;`). Maybe the same works validation as well. However since your question lacks any code and/or examples it's hard to know an exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

Where `i` is the sheet number:

```
worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[i];
```

Where `D17` is the cell address with the validation:

```
var v = worksheet.DataValidations["D17"];

if (v != null)
{
    worksheet.DataValidations.Remove(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove datavalidations by calling the Remove or RemoveAll functions on the ExcelDataValidationCollection class in EPPlus. The RemoveAll function takes a lambda as input parameter, so you can specify the conditions for which validation to remove.

```
myWorksheet.DataValidations.RemoveAll(x => /*conditions goes here*/);
```